# How to get multiple columns as list in SQL Server sub queries for C# .net core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

I have done this way, which id good..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getStateWiseCompany]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ProposalActualTemp TABLE
                                (
                                    RegionId    INT,
                                    Code        NVARCHAR(MAX),
                                    CompanyName NVARCHAR(MAX),
                                    FirstName   NVARCHAR(MAX),
                                    OfficePhone FLOAT
                                );

    INSERT INTO @ProposalActualTemp
        SELECT 
            Companies.RegionId, Companies.Code,
            Companies.CompanyName,
            Users.FirstName,
            Companies.OfficePhone
        FROM 
            Companies
        INNER JOIN 
            Users ON Companies.DirectorId = Users.Id;

    SELECT 
        States.Id AS Id,
        States.StateName,
        States.IsRegion AS STATUS,
        Users.FirstName + ' ' + Users.LastName AS RegionDirector,
        ISNULL(Users.PhoneNumber, '') AS PhoneNumber,
        (SELECT 
             Code, CompanyName, FirstName, OfficePhone
         FROM @ProposalActualTemp
         WHERE RegionId = States.Id 
         FOR XML PATH('CompanyList'), ROOT('StateWiseCompanyGroup'), TYPE) AS CompanyListString
     FROM 
         States
     INNER JOIN 
         Users ON States.RegionDirector = Users.Id;
END;
```

But without using xml serialize is it possible?

Example :

```
SELECT
    table1.Id,
    table1.Name,
    (SELECT data1, data2 FROM table2 WHERE table2.table1Id = table1.Id)
FROM
    table1
```

Something like this is possible to directly insert into .NET Core / Entity Framework Core model?

Comment: Why don't you use a `JOIN` to link the two tables?

Comment: @marc_s I suspect because the subquery returns multiple rows, which then causes some of the joined data to repeat. I think it's more a question based on misunderstanding data modelling than a problem to be solved..

Comment: @CaiusJard Seems like something EF Core is meant to solve already with Related Entities and Navigation Properties, i.e.: [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning indeed, it's something that ORMs have been aiming to solve since they were invented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't completely clear to me what the overall goal is/what these queries do for you (example output would help) but it seems like there's a misunderstanding about the role/intention of Entity Framework

Because it models entities - like User, State, Company - and understands how to work with them when these things relate to each other in a 1:1, 1:many or many:many way, you shouldn't be focusing on the goal of "writing an sql query that returns a single state with a list of all its companies in one of its columns" - that's the bit that EF does for you. You'd tell EF (or let it work it out by convention) that a State has a list of companies, then you'd retrieve some States (lets say all in the south), and they'd have a list property that cited their multiple Company. You wouldn't need to micromanage the list of Company in State ID 1's Company list; EF makes sure that the Company object in there are all the companies that relate to State 1

How EF chose to form that list is up to EF - maybe it retrieved the list of southern states with `SELECT * FROM states WHERE region = 'south'`, got 10 states then looped over the list running 10 queries of `SELECT * FROM companies WHERE stateid = @x`. Maybe it ran `SELECT * FROM companies WHERE stateid IN (SELECT ID FROM states WHERE states.region = 'south')`. Maybe it even ran the joined version `SELECT * FROM companies INNER JOIN states ON ... WHERE states.region = 'south'` and then sorted out the duplicated state data. Maybe it doesn't even try to load the companies for a State if all you've requested is the State (as a concept, this is called lazy loading); it could load that later if you ever accessed the Companies collection and it could choose to load the whole collection or it could choose to load just one or some, based on another predicate you've supplied as part of accessing the collection

The point is it doesn't really matter what happens under the hood because that's EF's concern and the EF team have (changed their minds how to do it over the time but they) worked out how to do it and hide it under an abstraction that gives you one or more State with all their stately properties, and also in there some kind of list/collection of the Company entities that are related. You don't concern yourself with fudging together some sort of Frankenstein "State with an inbuilt list of Companies in a string that is unpacked into a list that is a part of the StateCompanies monster", you just model your State as an object with simple properties and collections of other objects that relate to it, EF deals with the mechanics necessary to ensure that when you have a State it *looks to the front end* like it has a collection of related Companies built into the object

Comment: Please follow this link. I want exactly data same way. but in this link they are first serialize data to xml and then deserialize at c# side. But instead I need direct list instead xml format.

Comment: Was the comment intended to contain a link or are you referring to a link on the page somewhere

Comment: In EF asp.net MVC we can direclty assign list from xml to class list data like this.
But in asp.net Core with entity frame work directly assigning value to list is not happening as per above link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62954391/how-to-convert-xml-output-from-stored-procedure-to-c-sharp-object-in-asp-net-cor/63006535#63006535

Comment: [XmlRoot("OrderItemGroup")]
public class OrderItemGroup
{
public OrderItemGroup() { OrderItemlist = new List<RequestdetailModel>();}
[XmlElement("OrderedItem", typeof(RequestdetailModel))]
public List<RequestdetailModel> OrderItemlist { get; set; }
}
public class xyzmodel
{
public int id{ get; set;}
public string name{ get; set;}
public List<RequestdetailModel> OrderedItem { get; set; }
private string OrderedItemString{set
{this.OrderedItem = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? Utility.DeserializeFromXMLNew<OrderItemGroup>(value).OrderItemlist : new OrderItemGroup().OrderItemlist;}}}

Comment: What I'm trying to say is; you're making your life needlessly hard work - you have two things, State and Company, that are in a 1:M relationship such that one state has many companies,and you're writing a query to deliver states, and pack companies into a string so that multiple related companies can be delivered along with the single state, and then you're trying to find a way to unpack the string back to a list of companies at the other end.. and it's all pointless because EF already understands what a relationship is, and you tell it "one state has many companies. the end"